# How to fix definition of predicate in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I have the next facts:

```
some(t, j).
some(a, t).
some(p, j).
```

Now, I want to write a predicate in format `find(value_from_my_facts, is_on_the_first_place)`, where `is_on_the_first_place` can be:

```
first — the first argument in my `find` is always on the first place(as `a` or `p`)
second — the first argument in my `find` is always on the second place(as `j`)
both — the first argument in my `find` is in both(first, second) places
```

What I meant:

```
find(t, first). % will return false
find(t, both). % will return true
find(a, first). % will return true
```

For this I wrote:

```
find(Letter, Type) :-
    some(Letter, _).

find(Letter, Type) :-
    some(Letter, _)., some(_, Letter).

find(Letter, Type) :-
    some(_, Letter).
```

But I have there several mistakes, for example, my `Type` is Singleton and it always returns `true`. How can I fix my code? If it's possible, explain me shortly, please

Comment: In your definition of the predicates, it sounds like instead of *is always* you mean *is only*?

Comment: You obviously need to distinguish `Type` in each of your predicate clauses, which you don't do at all. You can simply do this by defining `find(Letter, first) :- ...`, `find(Letter, last) :- ...` and `find(Letter, both) :-`. I would also recommend a better name than `find`. It is very generic and doesn't describe at all what your predicate really does.